# Getting a Expected identifier or '(' issue in Xcode 6.1

Tags: c, pointers, hashmap, xcode6, expected-exception

I'm quite new to C. I've tried other links but no dice.
I'm using Xcode 6.1 and I get the following issues:

**Parse Issue: Expected identifier or '('**
**Semantic Issue: Unexpected type name 'map'**

Here's my code:

```
//hashmap.h  
#ifndef __HashMap__hashmap__
#define __HashMap__hashmap__

void map_init();
void map_insert(uint8_t, uint8_t);
uint8_t map_getVal(uint8_t);

#endif /* defined(__HashMap__hashmap__) */
```

```
//hashmap.c
#include <stdint.h>
#include "hashmap.h"

#define KEY_NOT_FOUND   -1

static int i = 0;

typedef struct HashMap {
    uint8_t KEY;
    uint8_t VAL;
} *map;

void map_init() {
    map = (HashMap*) calloc(1, sizeof(HashMap));                //Parse Issue
}

void map_insert(uint8_t key, uint8_t val) {
    int size;
    map[i].KEY = key;                                           //Parse Issue
    map[i].VAL = val;                                           //Parse Issue
    i++;
    size = i + 1;
    map = (HashMap*) realloc(map, size * sizeof(HashMap));      //Parse Issue
}

int map_search(HashMap map[], uint8_t key) {
    int index, size = i;
    for(index = 0; index <= size; index++)
        if(map[index].KEY == key)
            return index;
    return KEY_NOT_FOUND;
}

uint8_t map_getVal(uint8_t key) {
    return map[map_search(map, key)].VAL;                       //Semantic Issue
}
```

I tried replacing **map[i]** with the pointer array notation **(map + i)** yields the same result. Also feel free to point out how my hashmap will flop after the issues are fixed.

Comment: Your hashmap will flop because it's not a hashmap.

Comment: your `map` is a type.

Comment: you map variable in `map_insert` `map_getVal` are not declared. in `map_init` map is allocated, but not returned, you haven't stored it.  You can either make `map` a static variable or stor the value and pass `map` in for every function call, just like what you did with `map_search`

Comment: You aren't declaring a variable with *map, but a type. Also, if you want to expose struct HashMap to other .c files you are linking with, you will need to move your struct definition to hashmap.h.

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc`, `calloc`, nor `realloc`.  Instead, include `stdlib.h`.

Comment: generally, C coding practice is for #define names to be all CAPS separated by underscore.  I.E. #define HASHMAP_H.   Note, do not prefix names with underscores.  That is 'reserved' for the compiler to do so can cause problems

Comment: regarding this line: (and most/all the other references to 'map') 'map = (HashMap*) calloc(1, sizeof(HashMap));'  the struct was given a typedef name of 'map' (always a bad idea to typedef a struct)  so each instance of the struct needs to be declared as: 'map myMap'  and fields referenced as: 'myMap->fieldName'  the 'map' is typedef'd to be a pointer, which is very misleading in the rest of the code. (another good reason to not typedef a struct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
typedef struct HashMap {
    uint8_t KEY;
    uint8_t VAL;
} *map;
```

with:

```
typedef struct HashMap {
    uint8_t KEY;
    uint8_t VAL;
} HashMap ;

HashMap *map;
```

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to give you an upvote. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The typedef:

```
typedef struct HashMap {
uint8_t KEY;
uint8_t VAL;
} *mapEntry;
```

defines a new *type* called `*mapEntry`. You can then create an actual variable:

```
mapEntry map;
```

Now, the rest of your code should be parsable as `map` refers to the variable and not the type.

Comment: `map` is actually a type of pointer to the struct. But the op is using it as variable.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Apologies, my most recent experience with C was a crappy knockoff called "RobotC" (language was not my choice). It didn't really support pointers and I've forgotten a good portion of the syntax.